# Can't connect to Oracle DB ORA-12560 error

Tags: linux, oracle, database-connection

I've downloaded test Oracle EDQ test database, created a DB using Database Configuration Assistant and created a user.

I've granted him these privileges:

- all Privileges
- connect
- resource
- select on v_$sysstat
- create session
- create table

when I'm connecting to this service called 'eratest' locally I can do it without problems by executing:
*sqlplus localhost/eratest*

However when I'm doing the same but from different machine I get this:

*sqlplus edqtrn:1521/era_test* (I've also tried connecting by using SID eratest, but I've read that that might be wrong.)

```
SQLPlus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Sep 14 12:38:08 2017 Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Enter user-name: c##kuba

Enter password:

ERROR:ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

I've got era_test in tnsnames.ora file (if it's required I can copy paste whole contents of tnsnames.ora

```
ERA_TEST = 

 (DESCRIPTION =

   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.3.51)(PORT=1521))

   (CONNECT DATA =



(SERVER = DEDICATED)

  (SERVICE_NAME = ERA_TEST)

  (INSTANCE_NAME = ERATEST)

   )

  )
```

Here's m Listener.ora file:

```
listener.ora Network Configuration File: /apps/app/oracledb/oracle-base/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora

Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

 USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_LISTENER=on

 LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =

     (DESCRIPTION =

>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))

>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

>     )   )
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check the status of listener by executing this command from shell/cmd:

```
$>lsnrctl status
```

and then try to ping the Oracle instance by executing from shell/cmd

```
$>tnsping your_oracle@SID
```

It can be firewall settings. 
Check the status of iptables service. If it is your test environment, you can disable this service by executing from shell:

```
$>service iptables stop
$>chkconfig iptables off
```

Or you can simple open port 1521 by using iptables (works on RHEL/Centos):

```
$>iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1521 -j ACCEPT
$>service iptables save
```

Comment: So:

lsnrctl status doesn't return eratest service at any point. Maybe this is why I can't connect? If that's true can I manually start it up?

Currently summary looks like that:

Service "EDQREPOSITORYXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

There are other services for the same instance (can't paste them all here), if it helps I can paste them in another comment.

As for the latter:
-Machine responds to ping
-disabling iptables doesn't help

Comment: So "Instance orcl status READY" means that there are no problems in oracle. May be it is SELinux, check config file in /etc/selinux/config, and if the mode is "enforsing" then change it to "permissive"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far.
SELinux was changed from enfrocing to permissive, I've restarted the server (just to be sure). There's one change, when I'm trying to log in locally (using sqlplus) sqlplus returns: `ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA`. After that I'm prompted for login, i input the same login as I used with easy connect and it works.
When doing the same remotely there's no change (even when using the same easy connect command), I still get `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`

Comment: One more question: if services summary (from lsnrctl status) returns every service, but not the one that I'm trying to connect to (era_test) should I be worried/investigate further?
Or if I can connect locally using this service, that means that it should work too.
Also, maybe there are some kind of permissions that I forgot/didn't know about.

Comment: If there is no service in "lsnrctl services" you should register it manually. Just add information about it in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora` file.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you so much, but could you help me with it?
Looking at the contents of listener.ora I can't find any key on how to input that service in this file.
Here's what I have in this file at the moment:
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /apps/app/oracledb/oracle-base/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_LISTENER=on

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
)
)

Comment: Please, look at the article in this link (https://avdeo.com/2013/04/12/instanceservice_registration/)
And look for the "Static Service Registration:" chapter.

Comment: OK, I've been following the article you sent me (big thanks by the way), however it still didn't help me.
Here's how my listener.ora file looks like right [now](https://imgur.com/a/J1Btr)
I've tried inputting different oracle_home locations, but nothing helped.
I've also tried chmod 777 for /dbhome_1, this also didn't helped.

Comment: And did you do listener restart after changing the file? 
`$>lsnrctl restart`

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply and sorry for the delayed response.
As for the restart- restarting listener after changing the file there is no change in behaviour.
Here are [link]screenshots(https://imgur.com/a/HFHwu)[/link] showing results that I get when trying to start listener using settings shown in previous comment.